# Recode categorical variable with multiple values to binary variable in Python

Tags: python, binary, recode

I want to recode a categorical variable with multiple values in to a binary variable in python.

As follows:

**Column name**: Donation Willingness

**Values**:

1. Yes I want to donate: 132 female respondents
2. No I did not donate, but I want to do it in the future: 2743 female respondents
3. Yes I did donate, but not anymore: 138 female respondents
4. No I did not donate, but dont want it also in the future: 10323 female respondents

Desirable scenario is a binary variable of Donation Willingness of 1 and 0, whereby 1 = value 1 and 2, and 0 = value 3 and 4.

How do I do this with Python?

Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy conditional indexing.

```
y[y == 2] = 1
y[y >= 3] = 0
```